# Title and rightBarButtonItem dissapear from UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

I use a `UIViewController` to list out items in 2 separate places. One place is its default home and another is where another controller pushes it onto a nav stack to view a list of items.

Both places allows you to add new items to it by clicking an add button in the navBar. The list's behavior is decided based on a `NSObject *` called `targetController` that is set by its caller to its `self` reference, otherwise it's `nil` by default.

I ran into an issue where if you had them both showing at the same time in separate tabs of a tabBar the navBar `title`/`rightBarButtonItem` would disappear on the one called first. I finally figured out that the navBar was replacing the `items` stack whenever the list's view was pushed causing the `navigationItem` to be removed.

My only solution is to force the list's view to be popped whenever a tabBar button item is pressed. **Is there a better way?**

BTW, I chose to use the same controller in 2 different places to avoid duplicate functionality and thus maintain less code.

Comment: Are you showing the same instance of the controller in both places?

Comment: Yes I am and I use the root tab bar controller to hold references to each instance for lazy loading them in. I could use different instances I suppose, but I already addressed it by having the root tab bar popToRoot when a tab item is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that popping and pushing views on and off of the navigation stack is exactly the Right way to go about handling switching views, and that if you're tabbing away from the navigation all-together, popping views is probably a good way to keep the memory usage low. Just remember to release them as well.